# Combine RGB Of Different Dimension

Tags: matlab, matrix, rgb

I am newbie to `Matlab` Programming,

i have `R` , `G` , `B` values with different size(for example dimension R is 30000x1 and G is 35000x1) and want to make them same size to use `cat(3,RColor , GColor, BColor);` to combine them and produce image.

Comment: you cant, not unless you drop some elements or interpolate the vectors to be of same size

Comment: @Amro can i store them in for example 40000x1 matrix and have 0 for empty indexes?

Comment: yes you can do that too (padding by zeros)

Comment: It might help to add something about the meanings of these vectors, and what you hope to achieve visually by combining them. Also it never hurts to show the code you have so far, because it focuses the question, making it easier to answer, and for you to get what you really need to help, not a best guess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might `resample` all your `R`,`G` and `B` vectors to have the same length.
You can choose an arbitrary length like `m = 4000`, to interpolate data by factor of `m` and decimate it by factor of `length(~)`.

```
m = 4000;
R = double(R);
G = double(G);
B = double(B);
R = resample(R,m,length(R));
G = resample(G,m,length(G));
B = resample(B,m,length(B));
ImageRGB = cat(3,R,G,B);
```

Then you could change them back to `R = uint8(R);`, if you wish.

Comment: Nice, however, you should add a bit of information of what you are proposing, not just a piece of code!

Comment: thanks but i get `The input signal X must be a double-precision vector` on `resample`

Comment: @Arash, Is your data `uint`? or `double`?

Comment: @Arash, You should change it to `double`.